# uigrid remove initial blank option from dropdown filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angularjs-filter

Here's the screenshot of my ui-grid.
[image]

Here's the code that creates that filter.

```
{ field: 'channel_type', displayName: "Type", filter: {
                                        type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                                        selectOptions: [
                                            { value: 'HD', label: 'HD' },
                                            { value: 'SD', label: 'SD' }
                                        ]
                                    }},
            { field: 'price', displayName: "Price", enableFiltering: false, enableSorting: false},
```

My data is loaded in uigrid from rest api call.

I really can't figure it out from where is it adding that blank option. I haven't found any solution to this issue. Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known issue, see [ui-grid issues](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3942)

The solution (workaround) is to add some custom style:

```
#grid1 div div select option:first-child[value=""] {
   display: none;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZiRvO9Uvq6WKjITczo3?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: But rather than doing it that way, isn't there a way where we can do it through code?

Comment: The issue is opened before 3 years and no one solved it. I think this is a most gentle solution.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I should settle with that solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  filterHeaderTemplate and create your dropdown in it. Here is the example:

```
field: 'yourField',
filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container" ng-repeat="colFilter in col.filters"><select class="grid-filter-control" ng-model="colFilter.term" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in colFilter.selectOptions"></select></div>',
filter: {
         disableCancelFilterButton: true,
         term: '',
         type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
         selectOptions: [{ value: '', label: 'All' },
                         { value: '1', label: 'Something' },
                         { value: '2', label: 'Something Else' }]
 }
```

Defining term will select your first option and the empty one is not going to show.